# Converting HttpClient to RestSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xamarin, restsharp

I have Httpclient functions that I am trying to convert to RestSharp but I am facing a problem I can't solve with using google.

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://place.holder.nl/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer",access_token);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/personeel/myID");
string resultJson = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

This Code is in my HttpClient code, which works good, but I can't get it to work in RestSharp, I always get Unauthorized when using RestSharp like this:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient("http://place.holder.nl");
RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("Bearer", access_token);
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.Resource = "api/personeel/myID";
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Am I missing something with authenticating?

Comment: Have you compared the requests using eg Fiddler to see how they differ?

Comment: I have not,as i have no knowledge how to do so. I'll look into this

Comment: PS: I realized that would not be possible as i have no access to the working solution anymore where the first code-block is used. I only have this (and several other) snippet to look into

Comment: I gained access back to the original solution, i monitored the new (restsharp) data but Fiddler is not registering traffic from the old app

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This has fixed my problem:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient("http://place.holder.nl");
RestRequest request = new RestRequest("api/personeel/myID", Method.GET);
request.AddParameter("Authorization", 
string.Format("Bearer " + access_token),
            ParameterType.HttpHeader);
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Upon sniffing with Fiddler, i came to the conclusion that RestSharp sends the access_token as Basic, so with a plain Parameter instead of a HttpBasicAuthenticator i could force the token with a Bearer prefix

Answer (score 6):

***Try this***

```
 RestClient client = new RestClient("http://place.holder.nl");
 RestRequest request = new RestRequest("api/personeel/myID",Method.Get);
 request.AddParameter("Authorization",$"Bearer {access_token}",ParameterType.HttpHeader);
 request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
 request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
 var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: Thanks! Still being Unauthorized though :(

Comment: Added Authorization header

Answer (score 3):

If anyone happens on this, it looks like as of V 106.6.10 you can simply add default parameters to the client to save yourself from having to add your Auth token to every request method:

```
private void InitializeClient()
{
     _client = new RestClient(BASE_URL);           
     _client.DefaultParameters.Add(new Parameter("Authorization",
                string.Format("Bearer " + TOKEN), 
                ParameterType.HttpHeader));
}
```